# Build failing while adding background music to app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have two problems.

1- I am using following code to add background music in my iphone app.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        sleep(5);
         //this variable can be named differently

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"%@/background_music" ofType:@"wav"];


    // the file is stored in MyApp/SharedResources folder where as delegate is placed at MyApp/        
            backgroundSound =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] 

error:nil];

        backgroundSound.delegate = self;

        [backgroundSound prepareToPlay];

        [backgroundSound play];

        backgroundSound.numberOfLoops = -1;


        return YES;
    }

    @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
        AVAudioPlayer *backgroundSound;

    }
```

By running this code i am getting build failed.Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My second problem..

Suppose I have to turn this music off in another `viewController` with a button. How can I do that. E.G `SettingsViewController`.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x2c03, 0x90870c5a libSystem.dylib`__kill + 10, stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x90870c5a libSystem.dylib`__kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x90870c4c libSystem.dylib`kill$UNIX2003 + 32
    frame #2: 0x909035a5 libSystem.dylib`raise + 26
    frame #3: 0x909196e4 libSystem.dylib`abort + 93
    frame #4: 0x90895b1b libSystem.dylib`_Unwind_Resume + 59
    frame #5: 0x016c8e39 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 345
    frame #6: 0x016c8ccb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #7: 0x0019e2a7 UIKit`-[UIApplication _run] + 576
    frame #8: 0x0019fa9b UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1175
    frame #9: 0x00002a62 myApp`main + 130 at main.m:16
    frame #10: 0x000029d5 myApp`start + 53
```

Best Regards

Comment: You need to add AVFoundation to the list of linked frameworks.

Comment: @Till oh great my stupidity... Also can you answer my second Question please. Its kind of important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a linker error, you have to link against the AVFoundation framework.

To stop the playback from another class/instance/wherever you want, you can have multiple solutions:

One. Declare a property on the class you want to stop the playback from, and set that property to the original view controller. Then access that view controller using the property and call a method on it to stop the music.

Two. In some central class, such as your app delegate or main view controller, add an NSNotificationCenter-observer and simply use notifications throughout your app without messing with properties.

Comment: @Till thanks! :) Feel free to add your correct comment as an answer even if it seems obvious (well, that it is) - it's good, it helps the OP, it gives you rep.

Comment: @H2CO3 I have added framework and now build works fine however my app gives error of Program Received signal SIGABRT. Can you please recheck my code and tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @umar Where? Do you have a stacktrace? (Sorry I'm a beginner in mindreading...)

Comment: well no stack trace. It just shows green line over         return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class])); saying above error

Comment: @umar please type `bt` to the LLDB console.

Comment: @H2CO3 Please check it now. i have added it in my question

Comment: @umar hey, sorry, that's not helpful either. Try to revise your code a bit, you're doing something wrong with memory, threads or Coca objects and it's not obvious from what we have hee so far what it is...